# Why is my website cutting off on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

I created [this website](http://www.oooysterfestival.com) with the original intention of having it be mobile. However I've had to take that function out and for the time being just wanted to have it so when you visit the site on a mobile device you just see the website as you would see on the screen. Not mobile friendly as you would want it to be but zoomed out so you can see the whole thing.

I've already placed in the  code to make it behave the way I'd like it to but something is happening and it's not working. Ive looked into the HTML 5 shim and other options for the viewport but I can't figure it out.

I've tried a few different variations of the viewport tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500, initial-scale=1">
```

This is what the website looks like right now on mobile devices

[image]

This is what I was hoping to make it look like

[image: like this screenshot]

Can you see what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have a meta-viewport tag in place? - and if so, what is it? What is the actual code you have tried?

Comment: Yes, please view my revised question. :)

Comment: Ok. I don't think it's the viewport tag anymore. It's your page layout. Put a border on the #wrap --- put borders on a bunch of stuff and trouble shoot... remove the viewport tags completely. Maybe put a width 100% on #wrap or whatever you find isn't working. I'm sure that the problem is based on many styles combined that were in your starting theme or whatever. Also, on a side note... that "platinum" text looks bad on iOS because you are putting bold on that font, but that font doesn't have a bold weight, so It's faking it and making it look doubled. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and suggestions. I will be fixing the font once I can figure this thing out, however I haven't been able to do that... So I will be starting a bounty to get this thing fixed up.

Comment: I've noticed you have two meta tags with `content="width=device-width"` but only the first one have `initial-scale=1.0`. Try removing the second meta tag (in the end of the header).

Comment: I had been playing around with these meta tags but removing that one does nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case you should not use any of the suggested meta viewport tags. If you leave the page without any meta viewport tags you should get the desired result in most mobile browsers.

You could add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=980">` to tell the browser that you content is 980 px, if that is the case. You seem to have a 960 px wide page but it may look nicer to have some spacing on the sides.

**[I find this to be a nice article to explain the meta viewport tag](http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho)**

**[And this is another article about using the meta viewport tag for non-responsive pages](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/viewport-meta-tag-for-non-responsive-design)**

The meta viewport tags that you have tried tells the browser a few different things:

---

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

This tells the browser that content width should fit in the device width. In order to use this successfully your page width should be adjustable to the device.

---

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

This tells the browser that it should zoom the page so that 1 CSS pixel from the page equals 1 viewport pixel on the screen (not physical pixels on e.g. Retina displays). This results in your page being zoomed in as it is wider then a normal mobile screen. Maximum-scale also tells the browser not to let you zoom the page any further than that.

---

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500, initial-scale=1">
```

This tells the browser that the content is 500 px wide and that you should zoom the page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You had the most informative answer with exactly what I was looking for! I know how to use media queries but for this website I needed to know more about how to properly use the veiwport tag. You explained exactly that in detail with the explanations and external articles.

Comment: Thanks mathias..that was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a css for mobile devices in your themes style.css file. Please write some css for various device like android, iphone, ipad, tablet pc etc.

Example:

```
* @media Rule */
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {here is your css code}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1024px) {here is your css code}

@media all and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 780px) {here is your css code}
```

I think it will help you to understand responsive css design properly.

- http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design
- http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/
- http://www.creativebloq.com/responsive-web-design/build-basic-responsive-site-css-1132756

Thanks

Comment: As you see in my question, this is not what I'm looking for. I only wish it to look zoomed out when visiting the website on mobile device. I just want to know why it's not working the way it should like so many other websites look.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to looked zoom out, then remove the viewport restrictions. It is limiting your field of vision and preventing it from sizing your site correctly.

You should only use the mobile viewport if you are reorienting your content based on screen resolution, like the previous example for responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the look of website in mobile same as you look in the Desktop. as i can see the screeshot you have provided. For that REMOVE the Viewport code which you have putted in header. Also be sure of if some tags are not correctly closed. it might be cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try only one of this Meta Viewports each time, remove the others.

Try this first: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your body tag:

```
body {min-width: 1024px;}
```

Should not effect your meta or media queries with this, but this meta as mentioned is a great one:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```